# Remove first character if quotation mark

Tags: mysql

I have the following two strings:

```
/Volumes/ISCSIRAID_04/PORTAL_ASSETS/NOVIYDISK_FOURLIONS_TRAILER
"/Volumes/newfile.mov
```

How would I remove the first character of the string, if it = `"`?

I was thinking:

```
UPDATE users SET data = SUBSTR(data, 2);
```

But then this will always do a replace, instead of only when it's a `"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `where` clause:

```
UPDATE users SET data = SUBSTR(data, 2) WHERE data LIKE '"%';
```

Comment: just as a side note for the OP incase there can be single quotes and or double you can just change the LIKE part to this `WHERE data LIKE '"%' OR data LIKE "'%"`